# IIS Server - website keeps showing default page

Tags: asp.net, iis

I currently have a couple of websites setup on an IIS Server. I have setup the Host Headers correctly but whilst testing using the Hosts file (By adding in the URL and public IP address) - it displays the default IIS Start page instead of the actual website, this is the case for all of the websites added to the IIS Server.

Any help would be great.

Many thanks.

Comment: hosts files don't have urls. they do hostname:ip mappings, urls are not hostnames. e.g. `domain.com 127.0.0.1` is valid, `http://domain.com 127.0.0.1` is not.

Comment: Are they properly set up within IIS? Are you sure you have the correct URL to get to the site rather than the default configuration?

Comment: Hi, yes - have checked many times, all setup correctly in IIS and in the Hosts file too.

Comment: So the default document is set correctly, home directory is mapped right and you've checked the logs that everything is coming in correctly?

Comment: Hi, yes default document is set correctly, with the correct root directories. When I try a ping test with one of the websites setup in IIS using cmd, the request times out.